# Designing Equality Constraints for an MPC Controller

Tags: optimization, mpc

I'm trying to implement a MPC controller for a quadruple tank process as shown below.
[image]

My system has the following constraints:

- The voltages applied to the two pumps are non-negative and cannot be higher than 4.5V
- The water levels in the tanks must always remain in the range [0.5cm, 15cm]

I am able to simulate MPC considering only the constraints on the inputs that I define in MATLAB like this:

```
du_min = [vmin vmin]' - u_eq;
du_max = [vmax vmax]' - u_eq;
U_min = getXr(du_min,N-1);
U_max = getXr(du_max,N-1);
```

where getXr is

```
function X_r = getXr(x_r,N)

         X_r = [];

         for i = 0:N
             X_r = [X_r;x_r];
         end
```

And after creating the cost functional and all the ingredients I iterate and use the **quadprog** function as follows:

```
quadprog(H,F1+F2,[],[],[],[],U_min,U_max,[],options);
```

which returns an optimal value. Now, I want to find an optimal solution also considering the second constraint on tank heights. It is an equality constraint, i.e. my heights (the states of the system) must be:

[image]

Now, being that the quadprog function doesn't accept >= I'm forced to change the sign of the lowest bound. I would like to have, generally speaking, something like this:

[image]

In doing so I define a matrix Hx which groups the identity matrices in the following way:

```
Hx = [eye(size(A,1)); -eye(size(A,1))];
```

and then I define a vector hx containing the maximum and minimum constraints as follows:

```
hx_max = [hmax; hmax; hmax; hmax];
hx_min = [hmin; hmin; hmin; hmin];

hx = [hx_max - x_eq; - hx_min + x_eq];
```

Then I have to "adapt" these two elements just defined to the number of steps N, and I proceed as follows:

```
Htilde_x = getHtilde(Hx, N);
```

where getHtilde is the following function:

```
function Hx_tilde = getHtilde(Hx, N)

zeri = zeros(size(Hx));
Hx_tilde = [Hx zeri; zeri Hx];

for i=3:N
    zeri = [zeri zeros(size(zeri)); zeros(size(zeri)) zeri];
    Hx_tilde = [Hx_tilde zeri; zeri Hx_tilde];
end

Hx_tilde = Hx_tilde(1:(size(Hx,1)*(N+1)),1:(size(Hx,2)*(N+1)));

end
```

By doing so I should have defined the Aequality and Bequality respectively according to the MATLAB documentation of the quadprog function. With the command:

```
[U, fval, exitflag, output] = quadprog(H,F1+F2,[],[],A_eq,B_eq,U_min,U_max,[],options);
```

I can't find an optimal solution. I can deduce that my problem lies with the definition of equality constraints. Could someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong? Thank you.